# Bootstrap table-bordered remove right, left borders

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a table like so:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
```

This table creates cells that have borders on all four sides. What I want is to remove the left and right borders, but keep top and bottom.

I tried:

```
.table thead>tr>th,.table tbody>tr>th,.table tfoot>tr>th,.table thead>tr>td,.table tbody>tr>td,.table tfoot>tr>td{
   border-right:none;
   border-left: none;
   border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

However, this does not remove the left or right borders, but it does apply a red bottom border, so I know it's at least processing this CSS, but with no effect for removing borders.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried breaking it down even further? Like border-bottom-style, border-bottom-color, border-bottom-width? And then not add border-right and border-left?

Comment: @BuddhistBeast no difference

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change this: `<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">`

To this: `<table class="table table-hover">`

And then add this css:

```
.table {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
```

However, if you want to do it the way you're doing it, the css is:

```
.table-bordered > thead > tr > th,
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > th,
.table-bordered > tfoot > tr > th,
.table-bordered > thead > tr > td,
.table-bordered > tbody > tr > td,
.table-bordered > tfoot > tr > td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right-width:0px;
  border-left-width:0px;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/IbebIpob/2/edit

Comment: I actually don't want the left/right border on the entire table, not the cells. I only have one column in my table, so I just want to get rid of those side borders.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3? If so, just table alone is top and bottom borders no left or right.

Comment: So only the .table class on the table will do that.

Comment: Ok, that gets rid of the side borders. Now however there is no bottom border on the last cell. How can I apply a bottom border on the last row of the table?

Comment: The fastest way is: http://jsbin.com/IbebIpob/3/edit .table {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd; 
}

Comment: @Christina how can I target specific cells in the table in order to remove their borders? I basically just want borders around all my cells apart from the header row where I just want the cells to have a bottom line. I tried adding the class .borderless to the td elements in my header row and this is how I defined it: .borderless {
     border-top: none; 
     border-left: none;
     border-right:none;
} When I inspected the elemenet, however, it was crossed out so it's not being used because bootstrap is overriding it, I think. any ideas?

Comment: In my case, this only works if I add "!important" after the color. Why ?

Comment: Likely because the added CSS came before bootstrap's css or bootstrap's CSS is more specific on their selectors. Look up CSS inheritance and specificity.

Answer (score 2):

try this style:

```
border: 1px solid #dddddd;
border-right: hidden!important;
border-left: hidden!important;
```